# Why is the first character in the CharBuffer returned by ByteBuffer::asCharBuffer always a space?

Tags: java

I encountered the following behavior while using a [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).  It looks like a bug to me, but perhaps I'm using the libraries incorrectly.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] byteArray = "hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
    CharBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).asCharBuffer();
    System.out.println(buffer.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(buffer.get(i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
6
 hello
```

What's the deal with the leading space? Am I doing something wrong? Is this expected behavior? If so, why?

Comment: [Can only partly reproduce.](https://ideone.com/WWxSmb)

Comment: Using jdk1.8.0_161.jdk on Mac OS 10.12.6 fwiw.

Comment: @Marvin you can reproduce in that way https://ideone.com/gXN8hs

Comment: @AmitBera interesting -  `" hello".getBytes(...)` produced an extra space in my output. Not sure what this tells us, though ;)

Comment: The extra character is `\uFEFF` which is a BOM (Byte Order Mark), probably because you are specifying `UTF-16` in the `getBytes` call.

Comment: I would accept OldCurmudgeon's comment if it was an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly about [byte order mark](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Byte_order_mark#/Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding).

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character, `U+FEFF` byte order
>   mark (BOM), whose appearance as a magic number at the start of a text
>   stream can signal several things to a program.

```
System.out.println(buffer.toString().startsWith("\uFEFF"));
System.out.println(buffer.length());
// let's remove BOM and check its length
System.out.println(buffer.toString().substring(1));
System.out.println(buffer.toString().substring(1).length());
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems your system uses `UTF-8` as default charset, while you are tring to decode `hello` with `UTF-16`. You can check it with:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding")); // UTF-8 on my machine
```

### Solution

- Since you decode it with `UTF-16`, you should also re-encode it as
  `CharBuffer` with `UTF-16`:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     byte[] byteArray = "hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
     ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
     Charset utf16 = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
     CharBuffer buffer = utf16.decode(byteBuffer);
     System.out.println(buffer.length());  // 5
     for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++) {
         System.out.print(buffer.get(i)); // hello
     }
  ```

  }
- If you are insist on the original code, you can place this code piece
  before it to make sure the system will use `UTF-16` as default
  charset:

  ```
  System.out.println(System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-16"));
  ```

Comment: Your code works, but I'm not quite convinced of this answer when it comes to ByteBuffer::asCharBuffer (the internal implementation is completely different from Charset::decode). If this is the answer, wouldn't you expect my original snippet to work if the Charset was replaced by UTF-8? It doesn't. OldCurmudgeon's comment on my question sounds much more plausible.

Comment: @PeterEnns I suggest you set it mannully in your code by placeing `System.out.println(System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-16"));` before the code you post. The original code works with it.

Comment: Setting the "file.encoding" system property did not change the output on my system. I double checked that the first character was indeed a byte order mark like a couple other users have commented. Thanks, though.

Comment: @PeterEnns That's really weird. Anyway,  it get fixed, that's good.

Answer (score 2):

The UTF-16 encoding is [specifically documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to produce a Byte Order Mark. If you don't want the BOM, you should specify UTF-16LE:

```
byte[] byteArray = "hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra details!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the encoding of your Java source file. Make your source file UTF-16 encoded and you won't see this behaviour. Since it is a String literal, it should be present in the code in the same encoding in which you ask it to decode it in the getBytes call.

For example, Eclipse defaults to a non-UTF-16 encoding for source code, because of which the string literal "hello" in the source is not in UTF-16, and I got the same result as you did (an additional junk character at the beginning). However changing the file encoding to UTF-16 gives the expected result. (File -> Properties -> Resource -> Text file encoding)

[image]